# How can I add password of user as alias in bashrc file?

Tags: linux, alias, bashrc

I have created alias for username and it works fine

```
alias yb="ssh name@hostname"
```

It works fine, but I also want to create alias for password, Can anyone help how can I do this?

Comment: What is "alias for password"?

Comment: Why don't you use keys instead?

Comment: password is too long and need to enter in multiple terminals..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Before we start, it's not a good thing to do... you should use ssh keys instead!*

You can use `sshpass`, it's a non-interactive ssh password authentication.

Install it using your package manager, for example in Debian based distributions:

```
sudo apt install sshpass
```

then in your bashrc:

```
alias yb="sshpass -p password_in_plain_text ssh name@hostname"
```

Comment: For Mac : Install "sshpass" using "brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kadwanev/bigboybrew/master/Library/Formula/sshpass.rb"

Comment: Why it's not a good thing?

Comment: I'm user (A), there is a user (B) using the same machine. I can use `cat /home/b/.bashrc` to see what B got there.

Comment: this is not working on my mac. any idea

Comment: not working in Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

For Mac:

After installing sshpass with

```
brew install sshpass
```

or,  **After 2022 update**

```
brew install hudochenkov/sshpass/sshpass
```

edit and save the file using the command:

```
nano ~/.zshrc
```

add alias

```
alias al.name="sshpass -p your_password ssh -YX username@host -p 22"
```

Then, apply the changes using the command:

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

use the alias:

```
al.name
```

[alias](/questions/tagged/alias) [sshpass](/questions/tagged/sshpass) [zsh](/questions/tagged/zsh) [terminal](/questions/tagged/terminal) [server](/questions/tagged/server)